# Shutil unpack archive - Can not unpack temporary zip file - Python

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, shutil, temporary-files

I am trying to download a zip file from the cloud storage in the following manner:

```py
import shutil 

  with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".zip") as source_zip:
    aws_util.download(my_buicket, "my_folder/design.zip", source_zip)
    shutil.unpack_archive(source_zip.name, "myfile", "zip")
```

While trying to unpack the temporary zip file created in the step above.
I am getting the following error:

shutil.ReadError: C:\Users\ryan.zhu\AppData\Local\Temp\tmppnn80v56.zip is not a zip file

I am using windows OS.

How to solve it. Thanks

Comment: You probably want to `source_zip.flush()` right after downloading, as the contents are probably yet to be written to disk.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible, that given file does not even exist and given error message is only making you think, that given file is somehow wrong.